# Htaccess redirects http://www... to https://www..., but does not redirect http://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make it so that no matter how my website is accessed:

- http://mysite.com
- http://www.mysite.com
- https://mysite.com

All of these redirect to the same place:

- https://www.mysite.com

The latter two, `http://www...` and `https://mywebsite...`, both work, but not the first one. The first one gets redirected to `http://www.//` for some reason. Here's my `sites-enabled/000-default` that does the redirecting:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.metalmetalland.com
    ServerAlias *.metalmetalland.* metalmetalland.* metalmetalland.com

    RewriteEngine On             
    #redirect all port 80 traffic to 443
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.metalmetalland.com/$1 [L,R]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#not https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.metalmetalland.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#https, but not www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This still redirects me to `http://www.//` for some reason. It doesn't retain the HTTP_HOST for some reason, like it literally sends me to www.//, not even www.mydomain.com//

Comment: @ebol4 I tried `http://metalmetalland.com` - it works correctly. Clear the cache and restart your browser.